# Entity Framework custom procedure with relationship

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, include, relation

I have a class called MenuContainer

```
public partial class MenuContainer : IEquatable <MenuContainer>
{
    [Column("Id ")]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int MenuId { get; set; }

    public int WareId { get; set; }

    public int Price { get; set; }

    public virtual Menu Menu { get; set; }

    public virtual Ware Ware { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(MenuContainer other)
    {
        return (this.Id == other.Id && this.MenuId == other.MenuId && this.WareId == other.WareId);
    }
}
```

and it has relation with Menu (every menu can have multi menuContainer).
Now when i want to load MenuContainer with relation i can use Include(). Like:

```
context.MenuContainers.Include("Menu").Include("Ware.WareCategory").Include("Ware.WareDescriptions.Description");
```

But my problem is that entity framework generate long script for this
(about 2000 line code of script and nested select and join)
so i decide to write custom procedure sth like this:(not what i want but simple one)

```
SELECT 
mc.MENU_CONTAINER_ID AS Id,
mc.MENU_ID AS MenuId ,
mc.WARE_ID AS WareId,
mc.WARE_PRICE_IN AS  Price,
mc.WARE_PRICE2_IN AS Price2,
m.MENU_NAME_VC AS Name,
m.MENU_DESCRIPTION_VC AS [Description]

FROM dbo.MENU_CONTAINER mc 
INNER JOIN dbo.MENU m ON m.MENU_ID = mc.MENU_ID
```

but how can i convert the output of my script to MenuContainer class???

(you know i should create MenuContainer and its relation "Menu" with output of this script)

I don't want to declare class, same as the output of my script and use sth
like

```
            return this.Database.SqlQuery<CustomClass>(
            "exec dbo.CustomeProcedure").ToList();
```

and fill CustomClass and then perform a lot of foreach and groupby and ...
to generate my MenuContainer class with its relation classes

what should i do?
how EF handle this issue?

Comment: Does the generated query perform poorly? You might just need an index or two.

Comment: yeah...maybe i can improve it by index... but i want to optimize the script

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that if I want to write custom procedure I should have a class same as the out put so I create a class and fill it with my custom procedure like this :

`this.Database.SqlQuery<CustomClass>("exec dbo.CustomeProcedure").ToList();`

But in this case as I mentioned, I had to perform foreach and .... to extract 
my classes and its property (like list of another entity). It takes time to write but 
the execution time improved significantly.
In previous case when I used EF include() it takes about 2000 ms 
but now it takes about 300 ms with all foreach and convert that i have done...

And I think EF does the same ( I mean convert out put of sp to class) at one of its layers.